# Why is my db_query not working?

Tags: nodes

i am trying to display my content types and their info in a table format. First thing i want to do is make sure i am connected to the database. It seems i cant connect to the database. Please assist.

Thanks in advance

[image: the query is not working]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've passed your query result into a variable named `$results`, then in the next line, checked a non-existent variable `$result` (no 's'). So your `if()` condition will never be entered.

Comment: Hi Jaypan. I noticed, and fixed the error. Thank you for the assistance.

Comment: Please make this as the accepted answer then